# bootstrap card not collapsed in mobile view

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am facing one challenge regarding bootstrap card while using  bootstrap version 3 .

Requirement is, cards(rendering list of cards in ng-repeat) should be collapsed in mobile view,only its header should be visible.

While card is collepsed,it should show chevron-down at right corner of card header and clicking on chevron -down card should expand and vice versa.

HTML -

```
<div class ="card spa-card" ng-hide="options.is_hide">
    <div class="row row-eq-height card-header spa-card-header">
       <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
          <a class="visible-xs"  data-toggle="collapse" href="#{{options.sys_id}}"
             aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="{{options.sys_id}}">
          <i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-2x dark"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-chevron-up fa-2x dark"></i>
          </a>
       </div>
      </div>
       <div id="{{options.sys_id}}" class=" card-body" >
        <div class="col-xs-12 card-name">{{options.user_name}}</div>
      </div>        
      <div class ="row row-eq-height card-date-label">
        <label class ="col-xs-2"></label>
       <label class ="col-xs-4">From</label>
         <label class ="col-xs-2"></label>
         <label class ="col-xs-4">To</label>
      </div>          
      <div class ="row row-eq-height ">
       <label class ="col-xs-6 card-date-values" >{{options.start_date}}</label>
       <label class ="col-xs-6 card-date-values" >{{options.end_date}}</label>
      </div>

    </div>
    </div>
```

css -

```
a[aria-expanded=true] .fa-chevron-down 
{
  display: none;
}
a[aria-expanded=false] .fa-chevron-up 
{
  display: none;
} 
#{{options.sys_id}}.collapse in 
#{{options.sys_id}}.collapsing {
  display:block!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same thing. trying to collapse a div on less than 992px.
for time being, I simply collapsed div for all pixels then using media query for 992px and 1200px, I called ID's collapse class to make display: block;.

CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #t10.collapse {display: block;}
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#t10">Some text</a>
</div>

<div class="card-body collapse" id="t10">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-2">
            Some more text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

as newbie, i spent hours on internet to find better way but no luck probably I used bad search terms.

if anyone can help finding better solution (without java), it'd be great.